# cakephp 2.0 Upload plugin

Tags: plugins, upload

I am attempting to use the cakePHP Upload plugin just loaded the latest version.

I am on a Bluehost server
PHP 5.

Crested a test table similar to the example in the documentation

here is the add.ctp

```
<?php
/**
    File: office_apps/view/VwImageTest/add.ctp

    Created: 3/19/2015 - mfm
**/
?>

<div class="imagetest form">
    <?php
        echo $this->Form->create('VwImageTest', array('type' => 'file') );
        echo $this->Form->input('code');
        echo $this->Form->input('description');
        echo $this->Form->input('image', array('type' => 'file'));
        echo $this->Form->input('image_dir', array('type' => 'hidden'));    
        echo $this->Form->end('Add');
    ?>
</div>

<div class="actions">
    <h3>Actions</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo $this->Html->link('List Images', array( 'action' => 'index'));?></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here is the error I get when the Add button is pressed.
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

Query submitted by application
SQL Query: INSERT INTO `thewoode_virtual_workshop`.`vw_image_tests` (`code`, `description`, `image_dir`, `image`, `modified`, `created`, `id`) VALUES ('PKFPBU', 'Vertex Click Pen Bushing', '', Array, '2015-03-19 12:24:29', '2015-03-19 12:24:29', '550b145d-0dbc-4764-845f-41ee45591f3e')

here is the Model file

```
    <?php

/**
 * file: office_apps/model/vw_image_test.php
 *
 * Image Test Model
 */
class VwImageTest extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Image Test';
    var $useTable = 'vw_image_test';
/*
    public $actsAs = array(
        'Upload.Upload' => array(
            'image'
            )
    );
*/  
    public $actsAs = array(
        'Upload.Upload' => array(
            'image' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'dir' => 'image_dir'
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
?>
<?php

/**
 * file: office_apps/model/vw_image_test.php
 *
 * Image Test Model
 */
class VwImageTest extends AppModel {
    var $name = 'Image Test';
    var $useTable = 'vw_image_test';
/*
    public $actsAs = array(
        'Upload.Upload' => array(
            'image'
            )
    );
*/  
    public $actsAs = array(
        'Upload.Upload' => array(
            'image' => array(
                'fields' => array(
                    'dir' => 'image_dir'
                )
            )
        )
    );
}
?>
```

LEt's try this again

```
<?php
/*
 File: ../virtual_studio/office_apps/Controller/VwImageTestController.php

 Created: 3/19/3025 by mfm
*/
class VwImageTestController extends AppController {
    public $components = array('Session');
    public $helpers=array('Html','Form','Session');

    public function index() {
        $this->set('imagetest', $this->VwImageTest->find('all'));
    }

    public function add() {
        if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
            $this->VwImageTest->create($this->request->data);
            if ($this->VwImageTest->save()) {
                $this->Session->setFlash('This image has been save');
                $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash('This Image could not be saved. Please try again.');
            }
        }
    }

}
?>
```

When I run the app and use the "Add" function here is what I get

```
Database Error
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Array' in 'field list'

SQL Query: INSERT INTO `thewoode_virtual_workshop`.`vw_image_tests` (`code`, `description`, `image`, `modified`, `created`, `id`) VALUES ('PKFPBU', 'Vertex Click Pen Bushing', Array, '2015-03-24 10:11:37', '2015-03-24 10:11:37', '55118cb9-81ec-44a2-b69e-391645591f3e')
```

Stack Trace

```
CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php line 460 → PDOStatement->execute(array)
CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php line 426 → DboSource->_execute(string, array)
CORE/Cake/Model/Datasource/DboSource.php line 1012 → DboSource->execute(string)
CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php line 1928 → DboSource->create(AppModel, array, array)
CORE/Cake/Model/Model.php line 1751 → Model->_doSave(null, array)
APP/Controller/VwImageTestController.php line 24 → Model->save()
[internal function] → VwImageTestController->add()
CORE/Cake/Controller/Controller.php line 490 → ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs(VwImageTestController, array)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 193 → Controller->invokeAction(CakeRequest)
CORE/Cake/Routing/Dispatcher.php line 167 → Dispatcher->_invoke(VwImageTestController, CakeRequest)
APP/webroot/index.php line 118 → Dispatcher->dispatch(CakeRequest, CakeResponse)
```

Has me stumped
Thanks in advance
Mike

Comment: Could you post your controller `add()` action code

Comment: Edited to include Controller

Comment: Mike.. I still dont see the Controller code

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I see that might be causing your problem is the use of `$this->data`. You should try `$this->request->data` as in the following in your `add` action:

```
if (!empty($this->request->data)) {
        $this->VwImageTest->create($this->request->data);
        if ($this->VwImageTest->save()) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('This image has been save');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('This Image could not be saved. Please try again.');
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the repose. Now I get the following: Not sure where this error gets logged. Is it possible that the Upload Plugin is really not loading. How can I verify that it is?

An Internal Error Has Occurred.
Error: An Internal Error Has Occurred.

CakePHP: the rapid development php framework
CakePHP 2.6.3

Comment: Did you add it to your `bootstrap.php` file as per the instruction on that plugin? `CakePlugin::load('Upload');` Once you do that, it will let you know if it is included or not

Comment: That's what I thought. Yes its there and the "Upload" code directory  is in the plugin directory. I'll reevaluate all the code this morning. I assume the error is probably due to a malformed CGI request. Need to figure out how the get error logging on the server.

Comment: OK so I create a vanilla cakePHP Sanbox and put the VwImageTest MVC in the Sandbox.

Comment: Added changes and error meesages and stack trace to original post

Comment: how can I upload file via ajax using this plugin?